# String Line Split with a Sequence of Numbers (Scala)

Tags: regex, scala

I have a poorly formatted string from a Salesforce query that is supposed to be CSV with a delimiter of my choice, but the API call doesn't provide a lot of healthy delimiters for lines or line items. The only line choices are LF or or CRLF. However, I know the 1st column is a number that is (8 digits) and each of the lines also end/start with `"`.

So I am looking for a way to split lines with double_quote, CR, LF, double_quote, 8 digits while maintaining the 8 digits. (I can lose the quotes.)

For example:

```
val lineSep = Seq('"', '\r','\n', '"').mkString
 
// desired lines returned
val a = Array(
    "\"09994931\"`\"abc\"\r\n\"def\"", // desired line with end quote gone
    "\"09994932\"`\"lmn\"\r\n\"poq\"", // desired line with first / end quote gone
    "\"09994933\"`\"uvw\"\r\n\"xyz\""  // desired line with first quote gone
)
val blob = a.mkString("\r\n")
blob.split(lineSep).foreach(x => println("**"+x+"**"))
```

returns 6 lines instead of 3:

```
**"09994931"`"abc**
**def**
**09994932"`"lmn**
**poq**
**09994933"`"uvw**
**xyz"**
```

Since I will later split lines on `` "`" `` ... so I'm ok with missing a quote at lines' ends and have an extra on start of the first line and end of the last.

I know that there are some lookahead / behind options, but I haven't nailed a way to accommodate those to signify the 8 digits.

I think code like this would be a start point, but it's not quite right - since it's not working I'm unsure whether to look ahead or behind and account for 8 digits too.

```
blob.split("""((?=\"\r\n\"d{0,9}>)|(?<=\"\r\n\"\d{0,9}>))""")
```

Note: To avoid confusion, mine mostly, there is a header that I am not providing and shouldn't matter if the numbers are included.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you get as input and what you expect as output. Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the newline also in to the assertion, you could a pattern without an alternation, splitting on matching a newline and then use a positive lookahead assertion `(?=` to assert 8 digits between double quotes.

Note that the `>` char in your pattern should not be there, and the `d` should also be `\d`

If you put the string between triple quotes you don't have to escape the `\"`, and instead of `\r\n` you could also use `\R`

```
blob.split("""\r?\n(?="\d{8}")""").foreach(x => println("**"+x+"**"))
```

Output

```
**"09994931"`"abc"
"def"**
**"09994932"`"lmn"
"poq"**
**"09994933"`"uvw"
"xyz"**
```

See a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/7B8wYF) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/frQBJY/1).

Comment: This is so close that you get the accepted answer  ... What I was looking for is `blob.split("""\"\r\n\"(?=\d{8}")""")`  ... just adding in the quotes to split to get the middle item ```**09994932"`"aaa\"\r\n\"fff**``` .  What is the purpose of the first `?` in the string?

Comment: @codeaperature The `(?=` part is a positive lookahead assertion (non consuming) that asserts that what is to the right of the current position  is ...  I think you also do not have to escape the 4th double quote in `blob.split(""""\r\n"(?=\d{8}")""")`